# CF7 Remove The Comma from Select, Radio, Checkbox Outputs etc

Tags: forms, checkbox, contact-form-7

I have a few 'select' 'radio' and 'checkbox' options on my CF7 form where the user can choose multiple options .. however on the output there is a comma between each item but I want to **remove this comma** so instead of the output being "apples, oranges, pears" it should be "apples oranges pears"

Contact Form 7 sent me a link to a very unhelpful guide and have since refused to reply for clarification on how to remove the comma with the select, radio and checkbox inputs.

So can anyone on here help me with the correct function to use for what I need to happen ?

This is the code they suggested but it appear to add a comma to numeric inputs only and not remove from select, radio and checkbox inputs

```
 add_filter( 'wpcf7_mail_tag_replaced',

  function( $replaced, $submitted, $html, $mail_tag ) {
    if ( 'your-number' == $mail_tag->field_name() ) {
      if ( is_numeric( $submitted ) ) {
        $replaced = number_format( $submitted );
      }
    }

    return $replaced;
 },

 10, 4
);
```

I am a beginner coder and learning by doing but need guidance to learn. Thanks

Tried to find a way to change the above code myself but it fails in the function file.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any way to achieve this without an extensions.  CF7 wasn't designed for form constructs beyond contact forms as such.

To achieve this and more I suggest you look at the [Smart Grid extension for CF7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/cf7-grid-layout/), a plugin designed to take CF7 forms to the next level  with a UI editor and smart dropdown field integration with your CMS data.  The Smart Grid allows direct control over the mail tags output with filters giving you access to the original submitted data (array in your case) and allowing you for example to display is as a table or a list in your emails.  For more details you can see this video [tutorial](https://youtu.be/mcC36e69-eM?t=1304) (this is for table constructs, but follows the same principle for all mail tags).

The plugin auto-generates filter helper code functions for your mail tag, so your field tag would have a filter that looks something like this,

```php
add_filter( 'cf7sg_mailtag_your-numer', 'filter_cf7_mailtag_your_number', 10, 3);
function filter_cf7_mailtag_your_number($tag_replace, $submitted, $cf7_key){
  /*the $tag_replace string to change*/
  /*the $submitted an array containing all submitted fields*/
  /*the $cf7_key is a unique string key to identify your form, which you can find in your form table in the dashboard.*/
  if('my-form'==$cf7_key ){
    $tag_replace = implode('<br/>',$submitted['your-number']); 
  }
  return $tag_replace;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Aurovrata appreciate your reply. However we use Ultimate Addons for Contact Form 7 as well and when I activate the Smart Grid, it knocks off the conditional, repeater and PDF generator fields from the other plugin. I will keep searching, bound to be an simple code that works somewhere lol

Comment: The Smart Grid comes with its own repeater, and the Condition Fields for CF7 plugin works well it.